# Annotations and extracted images from videos

Tags: python, image, image-preprocessing

I am working with extracted images from videos and I was able to accomplish that and I have an annotation xml file for the extracted images. As I am new to computer vision. I am confused about how to proceed from there and how to add the xml file to my extracted images. I want to prepare my data for DL model. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are extracting images from video based on video's FPS and each extracted image is stored in `images/` folder.

Use Annotation tool like CVAT, labelimg, etc and open `images/` using these tools.

LabelImg: https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

Get Started: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data

Comment: Thank you for your help. My confusion is that I already have the xml file but donot know how to connect them to the images and subsequently the videos they were extracted from. I want to create the train dataset and then test it but confused on whether I should test it on the extracted images or the videos and How to do that. I would appreciate your help

Comment: Use OpenCv to validate if xml file is correct based on images.

Comment: Can you please provide a walk through example on this part for beginners. Any resources would be appreciated